# Magento email template country code and double replacement

Tags: email, templates, magento, multilingual, country

To realize a multilanguage-magento shop we need country depended templates. But we used the storeCodes to realize languages which are different from country settings (e.g. there are countries with different languages).

We think to get the countryCode with the var-construct:

```
{{var customer.getCountryId()}
```

And we thought to include the necessary language blocks "generic" with the countryIds got from the function above.

```
{{block type='cms/block' block_id='email_footer_{{$countryCode}}' template='cms/content.phtml'}}
```

But i think, a replacement in a replacement will not be allowed? Or can we simple use variables in the code-fragment like:

```
{{block type='cms/block' block_id='email_footer_$countryCode' template='cms/content.phtml'}}
```

My goal is to not need to create multiple-country-if-statments for every country.

Thany you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every store view in magento is meant to be a language version of a store.

Create separate transactional email template or static block for each language and assign to store view meant for this language.

Transactional emails can be selected/configured per Storeview in system configuration. Blocks simply need to be assigned to storeview/language while having same identifier